# Java generics restrictions with interfaces

Tags: java, generics

abstract class

```
public abstract class Animal {

private int id;
private String name;

public Animal(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}}
```

_child of animal 1

```
public class Tiger extends Animal implements Dangerous {

public Tiger(int id, String name) {
    super(id, name);
} }
```

_child of animal 2

```
public class Panda extends Animal implements Harmless{

public Panda(int id, String name){
    super(id, name);
}}
```

_
Two attribute  interfaces

```
public interface Dangerous {}
public interface Harmless {}
```

- 

```
public class Zoo {

public static <T extends Animal & Harmless> void tagHarmless(Animal animal) {
    System.out.println("this animal is harmless");
}

public static <T extends Animal & Dangerous> void tagDangerous(Animal animal) {
    System.out.println("this animal is dangerous");
}}
```

- 

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Animal panda = new Panda(8, "Barney");
    Animal tiger = new Tiger(12, "Roger");

    Zoo.tagHarmless(panda);
    Zoo.tagHarmless(tiger);

}}
```

-result

```
this animal is harmless
this animal is harmless

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i try to restrict the methods of the class "zoo" with the interfaces "Dangerous" and "Harmless".

with the code

public static <T extends Animal **& Harmless**> void tagHarmless(Animal animal).

The Tiger doesnt have this Interface, so it actually should not work, does it?
But the tiger can also be added into this method tagHarmless.

I don't see the mistake.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are declaring a generic type parameter `T`, but your method is never using it. Your method accepts an `Animal` argument, which means any `Animal` is acceptable.

It should be:

```
public static <T extends Animal & Harmless> void tagHarmless(T animal) {
    System.out.println("this animal is harmless");
}
```

As for your `main` method, you are assigning the `Panda` and `Tiger` instances to `Animal` variables. Therefore, changing `tagHarmless` as I suggested means that neither the `panda` nor the `tiger` variables can be passed to `tagHarmless` (since an `Animal` doesn't implement `Harmless`).

If you change your `main` to:

```
Panda panda = new Panda(8, "Barney");
Tiger  tiger = new Tiger(12, "Roger");

Zoo.tagHarmless(panda);
Zoo.tagHarmless(tiger);
```

The call to `Zoo.tagHarmless(panda);` will pass compilation, and the call to `Zoo.tagHarmless(tiger);` will not.

Comment: then i get a problem with the class App "Zoo.tagHarmless(panda);". Required type T , provided Animal